# Redirect 301 with htaccess a url to another url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Recently I changed some articles in my site from one category to another and now I want to put redirect in htaccess so when user find it the previous address in search engine then redirect to new address:

```
example.com/sport/spdetails.php?articleid=28984&parentid=184&catid=184
```

redirect to:

```
example.com/sport/spdetails.php?articleid=anynumber&parentid=184&catid=189
```

Comment: I have 50 articles that i want redirect its url with catid from 184 to 189 but with one line code in htaccess.

Comment: Should all 50 URLs redirect _to_ catid 189 (_from_ catid 184 to 189)?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^articleid=(\d+)&parentid=184&catid=184$
RewriteRule ^sport/spdetails\.php$ /sport/spdetails\.php?articleid=%1&parentid=184&catid=189 [R,L]
```

`%1` is a backreference to the captured pattern (articleid value) in the last matched *CondPattern*, ie. the query string.

This is a temporary (302) redirect. Change it to `R=301` (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I have 50 articles that i want redirect its url with catid from 184 to 189 but with one line code in htaccess

Assuming you want to redirect these to the same `catid`, ie `189` (as in your question), then you can change the `RewriteCond` directive to read:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^articleid=(\d+)&parentid=184&catid=18[4-9]$
```